# How to retrieve data from firebase and input to csv

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with retrieve data from firebase. I want all the data to be inputted in csv. The problem is "only one data inputted". Anyone, please help me fix the problem.

thanks!

Database Reference

```
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseProduct = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Product");
    itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Retrieve Data from Firebase

```
    downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            databaseProduct.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String getDate = snapshot.child("productDate").getValue().toString();
                        String getInspector = snapshot.child("inspectorName").getValue().toString();
                        String getLocation = snapshot.child("marketLocation").getValue().toString();
                        String getProductName = snapshot.child("productName").getValue().toString();
                        String getPrice = snapshot.child("productPrice").getValue().toString();
                        String getAmount = snapshot.child("productQuantity").getValue().toString();
                        String getCode = snapshot.child("barCode").getValue().toString();

                        exportCSV(getDate, getInspector, getLocation, getProductName, getPrice, getAmount, getCode);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Save Data into Internal Storage file format .csv

```
public void exportCSV(String getDate, String getInspector, String getLocation, String getProductName, String getPrice, String getAmount, String getCode) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    isStoragePermissionGranted();

    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/StockCount/");

        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        File myCSV = new File(root, currentDate + " DataStockCount.csv");
        myCSV.createNewFile();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myCSV);
        writer.append("Date : " + getDate + "\n");
        writer.append("Inspector : " + getInspector + "\n");
        writer.append("Location : " + getLocation + "\n");
        writer.append("Product Name : " + getProductName + "\n");
        writer.append("Price : " + getPrice + "\n");
        writer.append("Quantity : " + getAmount + "\n");
        writer.append("Barcode : " + getCode + "\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit question by including codes, not screenshots.

Comment: sorry i can't share the code, i got error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: I put the code in the answer column, thanks..

Comment: You are not writing in [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.

Comment: @BasilBourque is it wrong?

        File myCSV = new File(root, currentDate + " DataStockCount.csv");
        myCSV.createNewFile();

Comment: Putting a `.csv` On the end of the name does not make it a CSV file. Read the Wikipedia article. What exactly to the three letters C, S, and V stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Add comma after each column data and new line after each row.

```
writer.append("Date : " + getDate + ",");
writer.append("Inspector : " + getInspector + ","); 
 writer.append("Location : " + getLocation + ","); 
 writer.append("Product Name : " + getProductName + ",");     
 writer.append("Price : " + getPrice + ",");
writer.append("Quantity : " + getAmount + ","); 
 writer.append("Barcode : " + getCode + "\n");
```